# Implementing a fixed run-time size array. Should move ctor and swap throw exceptions?

Tags: c++11, stl, containers, move, noexcept

The problem with `std::array` is that it has a fixed compile-time size. I want a container that can be created with a dynamic size, but that size stays fixed throughout the life of the container (so `std::vector` won't work, because `push_back` will increment the size by 1).

I am wondering how to implement this. I tried writing a class that contains an internal `std::vector` for storage, and only exposes the members of `std::vector` that don't change the size. My question is regarding the copy/move assignment operators, as well as the `swap` member function. Usually, move assignment is declared as `noexcept`. However, before assignment, I have to check if the `lhs` and the `rhs` are of the same size. If they are not, I must throw an exception, because otherwise, assigning `rhs` to `lhs` would change the size of `lhs`, which I don't want. The same happens with `swap`, which in my implementation is `noexcept` for the same reason.

I know I am going against usual advice to make `swap` and move assignment `noexcept` (Item 14 of Scott Meyers' Modern Effective C++), so I am wondering if this is good design? Or is there a better way to implement a fixed runtime size container?

**Example:** Suppose I have defined my fixed size container with the name `FixedSizeArray<T>`.

```
auto arr1 = FixedSizeArray<double>(4, 1.0)
```

The last line of code defined a `FixedSizeArray` containing doubles of size 4. Now define another:

```
auto arr2 = FixedSizeArray<double>(10, 1.0)
```

Should the following line:

```
arr1 = std::move(arr2)
```

throw? What about:

```
arr1.swap(arr2)
```

Comment: @LukasRieger Yes that is what I want. But I also want to define some `operators` on it, so I have to implement my own class. My question is about how I should implement my class.

Answer (score 1):

Do declare move assignement and `swap` as `noexcept`. But don't throw on mismatched sizes...

Since your arrays are fixed-size, ending up assigning or swapping two arrays of different sizes *can't possibly work*, in any circumstances. It's not an exceptional condition, it's a situation where the program doesn't know what it's doing. That's a case for an *assertion*.